# php how to output json encoded document in form without decoding

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony, get

I would try to show the steps leading to my issue.
I have obtained a document from my mongodb database as below:

```
$monrow= $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id))); //works fine
```

I then json-encoded $monrow as below (i need to use the json-encoded format)

```
$monrow= json_encode($monrow);   //works fine
var_dump($monrow);   //works fine
var_dump($monrow->properties);   //does not work where properties is an object.
```

Now my issue is, when I do the above I don't see the values of my form anymore (only see the json encoded monrow thanks to var_dump). I have to json_decode($monrow) to see my form again and by decoding, I get object(stdClass) in front of the values (which is not wanted).

The question is how do I work with json_encoded format directly in my form? or is it possible to ignore the object(stdClass) in the output of var_dump.

Here is my output for var_dump($monrow):

```
string(1804) "{"_id":{"$id":"52e0f51f64657635f1000000"},"campaign_id":1111111,"description":"test","interface_id":2121212121,"mp_commands":"","name":"full pack","properties":{"graph":{"cells":[{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":220,"y":180},"size":{"width":80,"height":40},"angle":0,"script":"Begin","group":"MP Generic","id":"953fd4dc-6a82-4ee3-b03b-7e3eba4c6f6b","embeds":"","z":0,"attrs":{"rect":{"fill":"#1DCC64","stroke":"#3E7F0C","rx":10,"ry":10,"stroke-width":3},"text":{"text":"Begin","fill":"#000000"}}},{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":220,"y":260},"size":{"width":80,"height":40},"angle":0,"script":"Send","group":"SMS","id":"5a158c43-f22a-4380-952f-173f309adfaf","embeds":"","z":1,"message":"Please call number 23094072304","attrs":{"rect":{"fill":"#FFC9C0","stroke":"#7F3124","stroke-width":3},"text":{"text":"Send","fill":"#000000"}}},{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":220,"y":340},"size":{"width":80,"height":40},"angle":0,"script":"End","group":"MP Generic","id":"827f9533-22d1-4331-b21c-5d12c291631d","embeds":"","z":2,"attrs":{"rect":{"fill":"#FF3329","stroke":"#7F1A15","rx":10,"ry":10,"stroke-width":3},"text":{"text":"End","fill":"#000000"}}},{"type":"link","id":"4fadab02-ef30-4a1b-9581-4bc2f03b11c6","embeds":"","source":{"id":"953fd4dc-6a82-4ee3-b03b-7e3eba4c6f6b"},"target":{"id":"5a158c43-f22a-4380-952f-173f309adfaf"},"z":3,"attrs":{".marker-source":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(0.001)"},".marker-target":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z"}}},{"type":"link","id":"694d255f-de4e-4a1b-b7e5-9634f6e529bd","embeds":"","source":{"id":"5a158c43-f22a-4380-952f-173f309adfaf"},"target":{"id":"827f9533-22d1-4331-b21c-5d12c291631d"},"z":4,"attrs":{".marker-source":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(0.001)"},".marker-target":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z"}}}]}}}"
```

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($monrow);`

Comment: thanks. I've added this info to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json_decode($monrow, true) to obtain assoc array insteed of stdClass object. But looks like you simply should not call `json_encode` directly after retreiving document from mongodb.

Comment: thanks Ostrovski. By doing this (true) i still get a page without the form but with the array

Comment: Try simply to avoid any json_* functions calls after loading data from mongo. It seems redundant.